# SQL Server : select distinct records with inner join and where clause

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

Friends I am stuck in a stored procedure. I am unable to display distinct records.

I have a name `USERS` and `Photos`. Both are inner join using `userID`.

Since the table `Photos` has multiple records the search result is repeated. Friends can you help me fix this please?

**Stored procedure:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.homesearch
   @gender varchar(6),
   @age int,
   @age2 int,
   @religion varchar(50),
   @status varchar(11),
   @Country varchar(50),
   @City varchar(50)
AS
   SELECT 
       users.userID, photos.filename, users.userName,
       users.FirstName, users.LastName, users.nationality, 
       users.Country, users.City, users.age, users.status 
   FROM 
       users 
   INNER JOIN 
       photos ON users.userID = photos.userID
   WHERE 
      (users.age >= @age) AND (users.age <= @age2) 
      AND (users.gender = @gender) AND (users.religion = @religion) 
      AND (users.status = @status) AND (users.Country = @Country) 
      AND (users.City = @City)

   RETURN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this using `CROSS APPLY`

```
SELECT u.userID
      ,u.userName
      ,P.filename
      ,u.FirstName
      ,u.LastName
      ,u.nationality 
      ,u.Country
      ,u.City
      ,u.age
      ,u.status 

FROM  users u
        CROSS APPLY
                  (
                  SELECT TOP 1 photos.filename
                  FROM photos 
                  WHERE u.userID = userID
                  ORDER BY photos.SomeColumn   --<-- Pick a column here
                  )p
WHERE (u.age >= @age)      AND (u.age <= @age2) 
AND   (u.gender = @gender) AND (u.religion = @religion) 
AND   (u.status = @status) AND (u.Country = @Country) 
AND   (u.City = @City)
```

Pick a column by which you want to decide which TOP 1 filename you want to pick from Photos table for each user in users table.

**Or using CTE**

```
;With P_CTE
AS
 (
 SELECT TOP UserID, photos.filename,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY UserID)
 FROM photos
 )
SELECT users.userID, P_CTE.filename, users.userName,
       users.FirstName, users.LastName, users.nationality, 
       users.Country, users.City, users.age, users.status 
FROM   users INNER JOIN  P_CTE 
ON     users.userID = P_CTE.userID
WHERE  (users.age >= @age) AND (users.age <= @age2) 
AND    (users.gender = @gender) AND (users.religion = @religion) 
AND    (users.status = @status) AND (users.Country = @Country) 
AND    (users.City = @City)
AND    P_CTE.rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Ali .... CROSS APPLY  logic did the job pretty good ... and i learned something from it.  once again thanks friend :)

Answer (score 0):

modify Your select query by :-

```
SELECT users.userID, photos.filename, users.userName,
   users.FirstName, users.LastName, users.nationality, 
   users.Country, users.City, users.age, users.status 
FROM users INNER JOIN photos 
    ON users.userID = photos.userID
WHERE (users.age >= @age) AND (users.age <= @age2) 
    AND (users.gender = @gender) AND (users.religion = @religion) 
    AND (users.status = @status) AND (users.Country = @Country) 
    AND (users.City = @City) 
GROUP BY users.userID, photos.filename, users.userName,
   users.FirstName, users.LastName, users.nationality, 
   users.Country, users.City, users.age, users.status
```

and it will return unique results.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.userID, photos.filename, users.userName,
   users.FirstName, users.LastName, users.nationality, 
   users.Country, users.City, users.age, users.status 
FROM users INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT userID FROM photos) AS P 
ON users.userID = P.userID
```

Comment: you need to include the `photos.filename` column too in your `P` table since is referenced in the main select

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is to reduce the entries in your Photos table since there are many photos for each user. In my example I'm using `max(filename)` to get the one with longest name but you can use other criteria here:

```
SELECT users.userID, P.filename, users.userName,
   users.FirstName, users.LastName, users.nationality, 
   users.Country, users.City, users.age, users.status 
FROM users INNER JOIN 
 (SELECT userID, max(filename) as filename 
  FROM photos
  GROUP BY userID) AS P 
ON users.userID = P.userID
WHERE (users.age >= @age) AND (users.age <= @age2) 
   AND (users.gender = @gender) AND (users.religion = @religion) 
   AND (users.status = @status) AND (users.Country = @Country) 
   AND (users.City = @City)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please clear some points Ali.

Your data is showing something like..

```
userID      userName ......... filename
1           ABC                c:/phot1.png
1           ABC                c:/phot2.png
1           ABC                c:/phot2.png
```

If i am correct, then their is two possible ways to show your data to make your records distinct.

**First**

```
  userID      userName ......... filename
    1           ABC                c:/phot1.png,c:/phot2.png,c:/phot2.png
```

This can be achieved by using `for xml path('')` OR `COALESCE`

**Second**
Show only one photo like:

```
userID      userName ......... filename
        1           ABC                c:/photo1.png
```

This can be achieved by applying some condition for  photo.

Comment: its pray time i am leaving web, hope this will make sense.